# Loop for, para poner dos imagenes encima de las columnas de un geom_col

Tags: r, bucles, rstudio

Hola tengo este código que me permite poner dos imágenes en las columnas de un geom_col y me gustaría saber la manera de escribir el loop para que me lea un url de fotos y me pegue la segunda imagen, sin tener que tener la imagen guardada en el disco duro como con readPNG, alguna idea?
este es el código:

```
plot <- ggplot(ratio_2, aes(x=Pos, y=ratio)) + geom_col(aes(color= teamcolor.x,fill=teamcolor.x), alpha = 0.76, width =0.36)+
  geom_text(aes(y = -0.5, label = Pos),
            vjust = -0.7, hjust = -0.8, size = 4, color="red")+
  geom_image(aes(image= url.x),size=0.047, position = "identity", nudge_y = 2.10)+
  scale_color_identity(aesthetics = c("color", "fill")) +
  ggthemes::theme_fivethirtyeight() 
g = list()
for(i in 1:nrow(ratio_2)){
  img = readPNG(ratio_2$carajugador.x[i])
  g[[i]] =  rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)
  plot <- plot +  annotation_custom(grob=g[[i]], xmin=i-10, xmax=i+10, ymin=ratio_2$ratio[i]+0.5, ymax=ratio_2$ratio[i]-7)

}
```

muchas gracias

Comment: En principio podrías hacer dos llamadas a `geom_image()`, la que hagas más abajo en la tubería unida por `+` va a superponerse a la anterior. Asumo que `url.x` es una columna en un df en el que tienes urls de imágenes. Podrías crear una segunda columna con la otra imagen que te interesa y mapearla a esa segunda llamada. Un ejemplo reproducible del problema y del resultado esperado ayudaría muchísimo.

Comment: Gracias. Voy a probar esto que me aconsejas, pero anteriormente me devolvía un error como que no era posible usar dos geom_image

Comment: Por alguna razón que aun no entiendo y habiendolo probado antes, no se porque ahora me ha funcionado perfectamente. Muchas gracias, problema resuelto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario hacer un loop, se puede hacer directamente desde la llamada a `ggplot()`. La idea es crear dos columnas en tus datos con las URLs, una para la que se ubicará debajo y otra para la que se ubica arriba. Y luego hacer dos llamadas a `geom_image()` con diferentes mapeos en `aes(image = )`.

Va un ejemplo mínimo funcionando. Es un poco burdo, pero demuestra que esta aproximación funciona.

La primera imagen en un fondo negro, la que va encima son dos .png con la letra A, en un caso totalmente opaca (tapa a la capa inferior) y en el otro caso un .png con transparencia (deja ver el fondo negro).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggimage)
data.frame( x = c("figura opaca", "figura transparente"), 
            y = c(2, 5), 
fondo = c("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Black.png",
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Black.png"), 
figura = c("https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/151-1516529_letra-mayus-red-2-alphabet-letters-big-and.png",
           "https://freepngimg.com/thumb/letter/85845-triangle-icons-alphabet-computer-letter-text.png"))  -> datos

ggplot(datos, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_image(aes(image = fondo)) +
  geom_image(aes(image = figura))
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando R 4.0.3 y todas las librerías son de CRAN.

Comment: muchas gracias, muy agradecido